# CSS media query for mat-list

Tags: css, angular-material

I am trying to get my material list text to shrink when size of screen is smaller. I tried creating a custom css class with no avail the text doesn't change, so I just tried to modify the mat-list class like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1026px) {
  .mat-list {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1026px) {
  .mat-list {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}
```

but the text size still does not change.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in your global `styles.css` stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
::ng-deep {
   .mat-list {
      .mat-list-item {

        @media (max-width: 1026px) {
             font-size: 10px;
        }

        @media (min-width: 1026px) {
            font-size: 60px;
        }

      }

   }
}
```

Note: Only works in `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` mode and considered as deprecated in official documentation but it still works as a temporary solution. Use `style.scss` approach suggested by @JuNe

Comment: `ng-deep` is depricated and shouldn't be used!

Comment: You are right. Completely forgot about that. Added a note.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the following can help you:

- Try linking your custom stylesheet as the last CSS stylesheet
- Place your media queries at the end of your CSS file

This way you make sure you overwrite any existing CSS.